# Creation of UnityContainer fails

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using NuGet I added Unity to my Xamarin.Forms Application.
In my App class constructor I want to newup a UnityContainer instance.

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
public class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        unityContainer = new UnityContainer();

        // The root page of your application
        this.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage()); 
    }

    private static IUnityContainer unityContainer;        
 }
```

Unfortunately a `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException.` Is thrown on the line `unityContainer = new UnityContainer();` as I start to run my app in the android emulator. 
What could be the reason to this?

Comment: I'm using this statement:
var container = new XLabs.Ioc.Unity.UnityDependencyContainer();
XLabs.Ioc.Unity Version is 2.0.5540.30735

Comment: I tried to use XLabs.loc.Unity. I added the package using Nuget, but now I have a different issue. There seems to be a version mismatch.
`Error 6 Assembly 'XLabs.Ioc.Unity, Version=2.0.5546.35668, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' 
which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35`

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.Practices.Unity Version 3.5.1.0, not 3.5.0.0.

Comment: Looking at the referenced Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll file properties it shows file and product version 3.5.1404.0. Looking at the properties with in Visualstudio it shows Version 3.5.0.0. I already unloaded an reloaded the Reference, but that brings no changes.

Comment: It sounds like your environment is a bit dirty, I would suggest to clean it until you'll see the version 3.5.1404.0 in VS. a reset to cache might solve it

Comment: I cleared the cache "ComponentModelCache" as well as the "Tools->Options->NugetPackageManager -> Clear package cache". No success. I even unstalled the XLabs-Ioc-Unity package before.

Comment: Looking at the unity package in NuGet Manager sais that it is 3.5.1401.0 but the Microsoft.Practices.Unity shows Version 3.5.0.0

Comment: Did you add the dll from here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/ ?

Comment: no, I used NuGet and installed XLabs-IoC-Unity, which brings Unity in Version 3.5.1401.0 with it.

Comment: I actually installed this version: https://www.nuget.org/packages/XLabs.Forms/2.0.5541-pre1 of XLabs, and this version for unity: https://www.nuget.org/packages/XLabs.IoC.Unity/2.0.5541-pre1

Comment: Using the packages you suggestet, solved the version issue. But now I am back to my original issue I am getting the `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException` again allthough I am now newing up `dependencyContainer = new XLabs.Ioc.Unity.UnityDependencyContainer();` :-(
I am just about to give up using unity. Maybe I should try a other IoC container....
Thank you very much for your help an patience!

Comment: Can you please wrap the initialization with a try-catch clause and post the exception details here?

Comment: Guys, I have the same issue with Unity version 4.0.1. StackTrace http://pastebin.com/wWUGjEzS